# Proving that an Epsilon-Delta Proof is not true

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

We write $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ if the following is true
$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x)(0<|x-a|<\delta\rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon)$

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be given by

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x<0$} \\
1/2, & \text{if $=0$} \\
1, & \text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases}$

We will show that it is not the case that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1/2$

**(a)** Write the negation of $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1/2$ using the epsilon-delta definition given above

- I attempted to find the negation of this and this what I got after some calculations

$(\exists\epsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x)(0<|x-0|<\delta\land|f(x)-1/2|\ge\epsilon)$

**(b)** Prove the assertion that you found in part (a)
Hint: $\epsilon=1/4$

- This is where I am stuck. How would I prove the epsilon-delta expression that I found in part (a). Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your negated formula is not correct: you should have $|f(x)-1/2|\geq\epsilon$ in the final bit.

Answer (score 2):

$$(\exists\epsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x)(0<|x-0|<\delta\land|f(x)-1/2|\color{blue}\ge\epsilon)$$

Follow the hint,

Let $\epsilon = \frac14$, then $\forall \delta >0$, let $x= \frac{\delta}2$, then $$f(x)-\frac12=1-\frac12 \ge \epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\delta>0$, we look for $x$ such that

$$0<|x|<\delta $$
and
$$|f(x)-\frac 12|\ge \frac 14.$$

$$\iff$$

$$f(x)\ge \frac 34 \text{ or } f(x)\le \frac 14$$

so we can take $x_0=-\frac{\delta}{2}$
with $f(x_0)=0$.